# How to query database if it consists of many to many mapping?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 6 and my project consists of Fluent Api mappings for my Entites. I used Entity Framework generator to generate classes and mappings.

I have three tables in database

```
-User
-Roles
-UserRoles
```

`UserRoles` Consists of both `UserId` and `RolesId`.

Entity Framework generator doesnot generate the UserRole mapping and Entity class. It puts mapping in the Role class

I would like to get the `name` of the role based on `UserId`. How do I query it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Arnold I am using Entity Framework 6

Comment: Yes, and you're not querying BlogPosts. This is just one of a multitude of duplicates.

Comment: What does it mean by that Arnold. can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

```
var userID = "bad5ea54-f32b-4450-ae50-883acdfda41d";
var query = from user in context.AspNetUsers 
        where user.Id == userID
        from userRole in AspNetUserRoles where userRole.User == user
        from role in AspNetRoles where role == userRole.Role
        select role.Name;
```

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for your reply how I can query UserRole because Entity Framework generator doesnot generate the Entity class as well as Mapping. So How can I query.

Comment: Is your context declaration like this: public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>

Comment: My Context decalaration like public class ApplicationDbContext : DataContext and DataContext is inherited with DbContext. I am using UnitofWork and repository pattern